# Incorrect shift-deactivation

Tags: synergy

I think I found a bug for synergy. I have tried it in 1.3.6 and 1.4.2 beta, I also got a user (frankivo) on the synergy IRC channel to verify it.

```
Steps to reproduce (on a client):
1. Open a text editor
2. Press one of the shift keys and keep it depressed
3. Type: ACTIVE
4. Press the other shift key and release it (while still keeping the other shift depressed)
5. Type: SHIFT

Result: ACTIVEshift
Expected result: ACTIVESHIFT
```

So, the shift status gets set to deactivated when any shift key is deactivated without checking for any other keys.

Hope someone can verify this and file a proper bug/issue since new users aren't allowed to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of a long-term bug in Synergy 1.  It is [top priority for dealing with](http://synergy-foss.org/pm/issues/19) in the new Synergy 2:

> ***Version 2 requirement***
>
> Modifier keys (and in fact all keys) must not get "stuck on", as this was the most >significant bug in version 1. The problem was intermittent, but perhaps unit/integration >tests can be used to test this.

The original bug has been known about and tried to be tackled many times for a number of years now.

If you think it should be reported as a separate bug you should do so with the [Synergy Issue Tracker](http://synergy-foss.org/pm/login?back_url=http%3A%2F%2Fsynergy-foss.org%2Fpm%2Fprojects%2Fsynergy%2Fsupport%2Fnew).  Note: you need to [register first](http://synergy-foss.org/pm/account/register).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Now I know it is being dealt with (albeit slowly). That's all, I'll just work around it until then!